# Dynamic Approach: Joomla open link to an iframe

Tags: php, joomla

would like to know how can this be implemented in Joomla. I have a module that parse links from a RSS Feed, Now I want all that link to open in an IFrame once click by a user. I think it can be done by using Javascript But the problem would be some user disabled there javascript.

I think it can't be done just adding a PHP line in my template, I would have to tweak the feed module to open in new browser. If you have better approach please, I would love to hear.

Basicall What I wan't is to get the data's from an RSS feed and parse it, and make all the links open to an iframe every time it's being click.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you template has an iframe to display the link, then when you output the links, give the a tag a "target" attribute:

```
<a href="<?PHP echo $someLink; ?>" target="myIframe"><?PHP echo $linkText; ?></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's gonna depend how the iframe is implemented in Joomla. Are you using the "wrapper" component? If so you may need to hack the core files to add a `name` parameter if it's not already there.

You could also try an iframe plugin [such as this one](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/style-a-design/popups-a-iframes/4144) which lets you add an iframe to the content area with any parameters.

timdev is right about the link. You need to add the target attribute to the links with the same name as the iframe.